# Django Form Field Filtering Issue: Unable to Filter Foreign Keys to Show Only User-Created Content

Tags: python, django

I'm having some issues working with filters on the forms of my Django project.

This the the form that i am using, and the field "Company client" was sopposed to be showing only the companies that have been created by the user logged in, but once i filter using:

```
self.fields['company_client'].queryset = ClientCompany.objects.filter(user=self.user)
```

It does not show any company at all. And when i do not use the filter, it shows the companies that any user have created.

**forms.py**

```
class ClientContractForm(ModelForm):
    clausules = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    work_order = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Ordem de serviço',
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    contract_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Nome do contrato', widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Insira o nome do seu contrato'}))
    address = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Endereço do contrato', widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Insira o endereço do contrato'}))
    installments = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Parcelas', widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Insira o número de parcelas do contrato'}))
    items = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Itens do contrato', widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Insira o número de parcelas do contrato'}))

    class Meta:
        model = ClientContract
        fields = ['work_order', 'contract_name', 'address', 'installments', 'items', 'clausules', 'company_client']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(ClientContractForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['clausules'].queryset = Clausule.objects.filter(user=self.user)
        self.fields['items'].queryset = Item.objects.filter(user=self.user)
        self.fields['work_order'].queryset = Contract.objects.filter(user=self.user)
        self.fields['company_client'].queryset = ClientCompany.objects.filter(user=self.user)
```

**models.py**

```
class ClientContract(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work_order = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    contract_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    # Value related information
    total_value = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    installments = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    # Items and clausules of the contract
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True, null=True)
    clausules = models.ManyToManyField(Clausule, blank=True, null=True)

    # Company associated with the contract
    company_client = models.ForeignKey(ClientCompany,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contract_name
```

**views.py**

```
"""
ADD A NEW CONTRACT
"""
@login_required
def new_client_contract(request):
    form = ClientContractForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.user = request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect('list_generated_contracts')
    return render(request, 'client_contract_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the user in your kwargs here:

```
self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
```

...but you never actually pass the user to the form. You can do this when you when you create the form in the view as the _init_function accepts kwarg type arguments

```
form = ClientContractForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, user = request.user)
```

Comment: That was it, thank you buddy, i've didn't noticed that!